# Not getting the refresh token in OAuth

Tags: oauth2

I'm using this:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=3MVG99qusVZJwhsnpw0Ov62MLLZLjNIZatabRXwIxuPnXlOwwS2tHJuZ_D1LcGuOpo5ZfFn6POz_re1f2iUQU&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success
```

Which gets redirected to (upon success):

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success#access_token=ACTUALTOKENREMOVED&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Findeni.my.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00Db0000000IC0yEAG%2F005b0000000hBMsAAM&issued_at=1433271628862&signature=1Il90AbUNRIy4%2Bfewvb5f7A%2Fahe0PSDJ%2BhS%2B8g53XqI%3D&scope=api&token_type=Bearer
```

As you can see, the redirected URL doesn't contain the refresh_token specified here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you configured this in Salesforce using Connected apps?

Comment: In the connected app it shows Refresh Token Policy: 
Immediately expire refresh token. The problem is, it's not showing any other option.

Comment: Found this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69161/refresh-token-policy-locked-to-immediatly-expire-token - which solved my problem. Thanks @heisenberg (I wish they documented this!)

Comment: Great.. enjoy...

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to specify the scope, like this:

```
https://na16.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=[your_client_id]&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success&display=touch&scope=full refresh_token
```

Specifically, this:

```
scope=full refresh_token
```

(This is what I use, and it works)

Comment: How is `scope=full refresh_token` a valid URL? It has a space in it?

Comment: This is a while a ago... add an underscore, it could be a typo... either that or a `+`

Comment: Yep, looks like a typo. `%20` or `+` works fine.

Comment: this "full" is misleading

Comment: Yup, it sure is... I forget if you can write it like scope=full+refresh_token ... possibly?