# Don't receive refresh token after successful login via Oauth

Tags: oauth, refresh-token

I have a web app that performs the oauth authentication flow following [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5). After redirecting the user to the salesforce login page using this url :

```
<a href="https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/#/salesforce/auth/callback&scope=full+refresh_token">
```

I don't receive any refresh token :

```
access_token: "******"
instance_url: "https://eu29.salesforce.com"
id: "https://login.salesforce.com/id/****/****"
issued_at: "1582677706824"
signature: "***"
scope: "id api web full chatter_api visualforce openid custom_permissions wave_api eclair_api"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

In my connected app setup I selected every OAuth Scopes, including : Perform requests on your behalf at any time (`refresh_token`, `offline_access`)

I saw these two answers that seem related but my setup seems correct given the answers :
[Not getting the refresh token in OAuth](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78394/not-getting-the-refresh-token-in-oauth)
[Refresh Token Policy locked to immediatly expire token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69161/refresh-token-policy-locked-to-immediatly-expire-token)

Am I missing something?