# invalid_grant: expired access/refresh token

Tags: refresh-token, accesstoken

I'm facing a issue and I can't figure out how to fixed it.

This month (2021, June) started with a issue, the access token of several clients aren't refreshing, request is getting 400 Bad Request status:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "expired access/refresh token"
}
```

I already check this out OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow for Renewed Sessions (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5) and everything is as it is specified. I have also tried with this Postman Collection (https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/folder/12721794-6e2703c1-faa6-4898-a839-dd234c0be8c9?ctx=documentation) (Salesforce APIs > Auth > Refresh Token), just to check in case the backend's implementation was wrong, and I'm still getting the same error.

A couple days ago (when the issue was affecting only one client) I was digging down and found this [question][1] and this [note][2] in the docs, in where they say that "the default limit is five access tokens for each application" and "each connected app allows five unique approvals per user. After a fifth approval is made, the oldest approval is revoked". So, I supposed that the user was tried to refresh a invalid token because currently he hitting the five allows tokens, but now, more and more clients are having the same issue so there's no make sense, is not a single user problem, or perhaps, those clients reached the five allowed tokens?

Since I tried with the postman collection, I was wondering if it is possible that the costumer key and costumer secret have some type of expiration, and if yes, how can I validate that?

I really appreciate any help that you can give me, because I don't know what to do or expect.
Hope you guys can tell me what is going on.
Regards.

[1]: [Connected App - avoiding a limit on a number of issued tokens + token expiration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65590/connected-app-avoiding-a-limit-on-a-number-of-issued-tokens-token-expiration))
[2]: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_request_manage.htm&type=5

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example

Comment: Can you provide some of the settings in your connected app?  Has that been modified recently? Is the refresh token policy set to immediately expire? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69161/refresh-token-policy-locked-to-immediatly-expire-token

Comment: are successfully getting the access token?

Answer (score 1):

This issue mostly happens when instance url for which access token has been fetched is not same as you are hitting while api call.

The OAuth token endpoint for Sandbox has to be https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

The endpoint for Production or Developer org needs to be https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

using the above when you get the access token it will provide you the instance url

[image]

Now once the access token is fetched we can hit the instance_url only for api call.

[image]

Verify if the instance URL receiving while getting access token and instance url for api call are same.